# Bootstrap carousel not working in PrestaShop

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, prestashop-1.6

I created a module with this template:

```
<div class="row gryfnieslider">
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="{$testval}/one.jpg" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            ...
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="{$testval}/one.jpg" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            ...
          </div>
        </div>
        ...
      </div>

      <!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am displaying this template using a hook (displayLeftColumn). I am also using the default-bootstrap theme.

**My problem:**

The carousel is not styled at all. Bootstrap's JS works well (switching the "active" class, etc.), but its CSS is completely not applied to this slider. I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Bootstrap's CSS is linked properly (columns in my second module are styled well), Bootstrap's JS is also linked well.

**I use these hooks for both of my modules:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row slider">
        <img src="{$js_dir}../img/big/slider.jpg" />
    </div>
    {hook h='displayLeftColumn' mod='gryfnieslider'}                
    {hook h='displayLeftColumn' mod='productsload'}

</div>
```

**This is how my module looks like from the front-office:**

[image: Carousel snippet]

As you see - it's not a slider, it's basically one slide after another, vertically.

Could you please explain to me why does the carousel behave that way? Why isn't it styled? It's column (col-xs-12) is styled well.

**I'd be grateful for any help!**

Comment: Do you have a link to show the page?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.

It occured to me that not all styles from Bootstrap are loaded to my theme. For example - columns were, carousels were not. I applied a fresh copy of Bootstrap's CSS and it's all fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Find in your /sass folder the _bootstrap.scss file and uncomment the row 
**@import "bootstrap_lib/carousel"**